# Show that the system $\mathcal{E}_B=\{A\subseteq X : B\subseteq A \ \ \text{or} \ \ B \subseteq A^c\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $B\subseteq X$. Show that the system
$$\mathcal{E}_B=\{A\subseteq X : B\subseteq A \ \ \text{or} \ \ B \subseteq A^c\}$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Showing the 3  below conditions, we will then have a $\sigma$-algebra

$(\sigma1)$ $X\in \mathcal{E}$

$(\sigma2)$ $A\in \mathcal{E} \Rightarrow A^c\in \mathcal{E}$

$(\sigma3)$ $\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n \in \mathcal{E}$ for any sequence  $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}, \ A_n \in \mathcal{E}$

For $(\sigma1)$:

$$B \subseteq A \cup A^c = X\in\mathcal E_B$$
then we have shown that $X\in\mathcal E_B$

For $(\sigma2)$:

$$A\cup A^c = X \Rightarrow\\ A\subseteq X\in \mathcal E_B \\A^c\subseteq X\in \mathcal E_B$$
since $A$ union $A^c$ equals $X$, then we know that both $A$ and $A^c$ is a subset of $X \in \mathcal E_B$.

For $(\sigma3)$:

$$B \subseteq A_n^c \ \ \text{for all} \ \ n\in\mathbb N \Rightarrow B \subseteq \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n^c = \left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)^c\in\mathcal E_B$$
then we have shown the 3 conditions and $\mathcal E_B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am not sure if this is the right. I think there is something wrong. I will really appreciate it if I can get some help or a little hint to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you didn't understand the definition of the system. First we fix $B \subset X$ then for example for $(\sigma 1)$ the proof is $B \subset X \implies X \in \epsilon_B$.

Comment: Is this wrong: $B \subseteq A \cup A^c = X \Rightarrow X \in \mathcal E_B$

Comment: There is no $A$.  All you need to say for $\sigma_1$ is $B \subseteq X$ (which you're given), so by the definition of $\mathcal E_B, X \in \mathcal E_B$.

Comment: it makes sense, but why is there an A then

Comment: what about my $\sigma_2$, is that wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first property is proven immediately:
$$B\subseteq X\implies X \in \mathcal{E}_B$$
Now choose $A\in \mathcal{E}_B$, then $B \subseteq A \textrm{ or } B \subseteq A^c$. We have two cases:
$$\begin{aligned}&\textrm{(i).}\,B \subseteq A \implies B\subseteq (A^c)^c\implies A^c \in \mathcal{E}_B\\
&\textrm{(ii).}\,B \subseteq A^c \implies  A^c \in \mathcal{E}_B\end{aligned}$$
by using the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra. For the last property
$$(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset  \mathcal{E}_B \implies B \subseteq A_n \textrm{ or } B\subseteq A^c_n,\,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Again we have two cases:
$$\begin{aligned}&\textrm{If }\exists A_n :B\subseteq A_n\implies B\subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\\&\textrm{If } B\subseteq A_n^c,\,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\implies B\subseteq \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n^c=(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n)^c\implies \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\in \mathcal{E}_B\end{aligned}$$
by using De Morgan's laws.